# jQuery Offcanvas menu from the right

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get the jasny-bootstap offcanvas menu to appear from the right instead of the default left. I have changed the position to left using .navmenu-fixed-right instead of navmenu-fixed-left and I have even tried changing placement in the javascript file.

It comes in from the right, but not sliding like it should.

original(left): http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/examples/navmenu-push/

from the right(kinda): http://jsfiddle.net/821ubfq3/

```
<div class="navmenu navmenu-default navmenu-fixed-right offcanvas">
```

Any idea on how to fix the slide-in from the right?

Comment: It seems it's sliding as the original link. If you change the menu icon to right then it does look same. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/821ubfq3/1/)

Comment: It's not quite the same. The original does a slide-in (from the left) the one from the right does a reval on the nav, which should be a slide-in as well.

Comment: You have given a link to [navmenu-push](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/examples/navmenu-push/). Are you talking about [SlideIn](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/examples/navmenu)? If yes then the markup has few different classes for it. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/821ubfq3/3/)

Answer (score 2):

Encountered this problem as well, the following CSS lines fixed it for me.

```
.navmenu-fixed-right {left: auto !important;}
body.canvas-sliding, body.canvas-slid {left: auto !important;}
```